# How to set dynamic default parameters for py.test?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a framework which working under py.test. py.test can generate beauty reports with params --html and --junitxml. But clients that using my framework not always type this params to command line where they using py.test. I want make py.test to generate reports always when the py.test used with my framework. And i want to put this reports with log folder. So i need to generate path for report in runtime. Can i do this by fixtures? Or maybe by the plugin API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you want to implicitly add the command line args to `pytest`, you can use the `pytest.ini` placed in the tests root dir with the `addopts` config value:

```
[pytest]
addopts=--verbose --junit-xml=/tmp/myreport.xml  # etc
```

Of course, if you want to dynamically calculate the directory to store the reports, then you can't put it in the config and will need to extend `pytest`. The best spot would be the `pytest_configure` hook. Example:

```
# conftest.py
import tempfile
import pytest
from _pytest.junitxml import LogXML


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    if config.option.xmlpath:  # was passed via config or command line
        return  # let pytest handle it
    if not hasattr(config, 'slaveinput'):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.xml') as tmpfile:
            xmlpath = tmpfile.name
            config._xml = LogXML(xmlpath, config.option.junitprefix, config.getini('junit_suite_name'))
            config.pluginmanager.register(config._xml)
```

If you remove the first `if` block, then `pytest` will completely ignore `--junit-xml` arg passed via command line or in `addopts` value in config.

Example run:

```
$ pytest
=================================== test session starts ====================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.3.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-48320357, inifile:
plugins: forked-0.2, asyncio-0.8.0, xdist-1.22.0, mock-1.6.3, hypothesis-3.44.4
collected 1 item

test_spam.py .                                                                        [100%]

--- generated xml file: /var/folders/_y/2qk6029j4c7bwv0ddk3p96r00000gn/T/tmp1tleknm3.xml ---
================================ 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ==================================
```

The xml report is now put in a tempfile.

Answer (score 7):

Putting this in conftest.py will suffice:

```py
def pytest_configure(config):
    if config.option.xmlpath is None:
        config.option.xmlpath = get_custom_xml_path() # implement this
```

The accepted answer is probably a bit more complicated than necessary for most people for a few reasons:

- The decorator doesn't help. It doesn't matter when this executes.
- There is no need make a custom LogXML since you can just set the property here and it will be used.
- slaveinput is specific to a pytest plugin xdist. I don't think there is any need to check for that, especially if you don't use xdist.

Answer (score 0):

Configure pytest.ini file with parameters:

```
# content of pytest.ini
[pytest]
addopts = --html=report.html --self-contained-html
;addopts = -vv -rw --html=./results/report.html --self-contained-html
```

Answer (score 0):

@hoefling's answer worked perfectly for me in conftest.py. the code looks simpler there.

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    if not config.option.xmlpath and not hasattr(config, 'slaveinput'):
        xmlpath = "test_report_" + str(int(time.time())) + ".xml"
        config._xml = LogXML(xmlpath, config.option.junitprefix, config.getini('junit_suite_name'))
        config.pluginmanager.register(config._xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep things more clear, pytest uses `argparse` and the `request.config.option` is a `argparse.Namespace` object. Then, if you would like to simulate a command line option as `pytest ... --docker-compose-remove-volumes`, you can directly attribute the option `docker_compose_remove_volumes` to `request.config.option` (because `--docker-compose-remove-volumes` is converted to `docker_compose_remove_volumes` by argparse module).

This examples inverts the default option for [`--docker-compose-remove-volumes`](https://github.com/pytest-docker-compose/pytest-docker-compose) which is false. But allow you to enable it back by providing `--keep-containers` option to pytest.

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--keep-containers", action="store_true", default=False, 
        help="Keeps docker-compose on failure.")

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def load_env(request):
    is_to_keep_container = request.config.getoption("--keep-containers")

    if not is_to_keep_container:
        request.config.option.docker_compose_remove_volumes = True
```